# Multiple select and format in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

In MS word 2003 was a feature when searching (`CTRL+F`) to check "`Select all`". Then you can apply format to all found fragments.

In MS word 2010 you can highlight similar way. But I can't find how you can apply format to found fragments or to be more precise highlighting is not selection so if you format you will format only selected fragment but not all highlighted.

So how do we do this simple action? - Selecting found fragments or selecting highlighted fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for `find and replace` then click `more` and you can `replace format` Is that what you're looking for?
[image]